# Regular Expression: Match with Containing and not Containing

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse through a log file which contains many lines with the word `ERROR` followed by the class and method from which an exception was thrown, like this:

```
2016-08-18 19:38:17 ERROR  [KUHOMNYXARCH] [ 47] [c43215c4-acfd-491b-b418-653b53195be3] [MultiFormatRoiStreamer.GetImageRoi]
2016-08-18 19:39:46 ERROR  [KUHOMNYXARCH] [ 46] [10ba0a0e-0ede-4d0e-a582-d7e811bb7ade] [ExceptionHandlingBehavior.ProvideFault]
```

I am trying to write a regular expression which will match all lines containing `ERROR`, but not containing `MultiFormatRoiStreamer.GetImageRoi` and `ExceptionHandlingBehavior.ProvideFault`. My attempts to use negative lookahead assertions have not worked:

```
ERROR\s+\[KUHOMNYXARCH\] \[ [0-9]+\] \[[0-9a-f\-]+\] (?!(\[MultiFormatRoiStreamer\.GetImageRoi\]|\[ExceptionHandlingBehavior\.ProvideFault\]))
ERROR.+(?!(MultiFormatRoiStreamer|ExceptionHandlingBehavior))
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Could you just separate the fields of the log entries and check the appropriate fields?

Comment: @AndrewMorton What do you mean seperate the fields? This is a flat text file retrieved from a production site.

Comment: Well, if the fields are separated by tab characters, use a string split function to get an array of fields. If the fields are fixed-width, extract the appropriate parts of the line with a substring function.

Comment: What is the environment you are using the regex in?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to find the line(s)

```
(?m)^.*?ERROR[^\S\r\n]+(?:(?!MultiFormatRoiStreamer\.GetImageRoi|ExceptionHandlingBehavior\.ProvideFault).)+$
```

It uses multi-line mode `(?m)`

Expanded:

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 .*? 
 ERROR [^\S\r\n]+ 
 (?:
      (?!
           MultiFormatRoiStreamer\.GetImageRoi
        |  ExceptionHandlingBehavior\.ProvideFault
      )
      . 
 )+
 $
```